# Export DataWindow to PDF

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am exporting a DataWindow to PDF using the below code
    ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Method = Distill!
    ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Printer = "Sybase DataWindow PS"
    ds_data.Object.DataWindow.Export.PDF.Distill.CustomPostScript="Yes"

I am able to export to PDF, but the DataWindow has too many columns due to which they are not fitting on single page in PDF. i.e. Half of datawindow columns are displayed on page 1 of PDF and remaining columns are displayed on page 2.

Can any1 help me in this case.
I want the entire DataWindow to be fitted into single PDF (width wise).
If it is not possible to fit the entire DataWindow into single page of PDF then can we set a horizontal scroll bar for the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the same.
Clcik the properties of Datawindow. Then select the "PrintSpecifications" tab.
Set the "PaperOrientation" property to "Landscape". Earlier it was "Default".
This solved my problem